# Wordpress show Edit and Delete buttons only if post's author

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, author

My wordpress site uses post submissions (actually, CPTs) from site members. When displaying the CPT post, I'd like buttons to appear for Edit and Delete when the author is viewing the post, and not appear if any other member views the post.
I've researched code and plugins, but all seem to only apply to the author role, not the specific author themselves.
Is there a way to use PHP function/shortcode, Javascript, or some combination of the two, to add this functionality?

Comment: iirc, members plugin has that sort of capability to fine tune permissions of each role, try it out, it can modify cpts too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for the disable edit and delete button. I've tested the code and it's working fine from my side.

**FOR THE EDIT BUTTON LINK ONLY**

```
function prefix_remove_get_edit_post_link( $link ) {
    global $post;
    $current_user =  get_current_user_id();
    $author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id);

    if($author_id == $current_user) {
        return $link;
    }
    return null;
}
add_filter('get_edit_post_link', 'prefix_remove_get_edit_post_link');
```

**FOR THE DELETE BUTTON LINK ONLY**

```
function prefix_remove_get_delete_post_link( $link ) {
    global $post;
    $current_user =  get_current_user_id();
    $author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id);

    if($author_id == $current_user) {
        return $link;
    }
    return null;
}

add_filter('get_delete_post_link', 'prefix_remove_get_delete_post_link');
```

**FOR THE HIDE BUTTONS EDIT AND DELETE**

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
    global $post;
    $current_user =  get_current_user_id();
    $author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id);

    if($author_id != $current_user) {
        if( get_post_type() === 'post' ){
            unset( $actions['edit'] );
            unset( $actions['trash'] );
            unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
        }
    }
    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: While I very much appreciate the code that supplies what will happen once the button is pressed (and plan on incorporating it), I'm still missing the answer about the initial buttons themselves. How can I hide them if the current user is not the original author?

Comment: so you need to remove these buttons right? @BrianWent

Comment: I've updated my answer please check and let me know if not working @BrianWent

Comment: Thanks for all the code! I have a bit of work on getting the actions working, but your foundation is great.